# Getting request time out error while creating Production order from sales order screen

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

Getting request time out error while creating Production order from sales order screen.

I want to create more then 1000 Production order from sales order screen's Action Create Production order.

When I click create production Order action of sales order then create production order popup will open.

I have selected  more then 1000 Production order and click on Create Production order button.

it will give request time out error. Please help

Comment: does configuring the query timeout make a difference? https://help.acumatica.com/(W(1))/Help?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=62b4944b-22d6-48d6-955d-f672b8ba1057
Also what if you use the creation production order screen vs the sales order create production order button?